# Drag and Drop not recognizing child of drag object in Animate CC

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, easeljs, animate-cc

I'm trying to make a drag and drop, but it's been giving me a bunch of issues. I fix one and another comes up. I had it working where it would see if any part of my drag object entered a target area, but I wanted it to just recognize one part (it's graphic of a pointy thermometer, and you can't measure temperature with the head in real life) [demo here](http://apersonnamedmike.github.io/drag-demo/).

The error I'm getting is that "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'drag' of undefined" (I labeled 'drag' on the demo, but its a child movieclip inside the drag object)

also, 'thermometer' and 'drag' are both named instances of movieclips.

The Code:

```
var dragger = this.thermometer; 

//tried this to see if it would help
var tip = this.thermometer.drag;
var right = this.targetRight;
var wrong = this.targetWrong;
```

- For moving it:

  ```
  dragger.on("pressmove", function(evt){
  evt.currentTarget.x = evt.stageX;
  evt.currentTarget.y = evt.stageY;


  if(intersect(tip, right)){
     evt.currentTarget.alpha=0.2;

   }
   else if(intersect(tip, wrong)){
     evt.currentTarget.alpha=0.7;

   }
   else{
     evt.currentTarget.alpha=1;

   }

  stage.update(evt);
  }, this);
  ```
- For releasing it

  ```
  dragger.on("pressup", function(evt){ 
  //lock position of drag object and play animation if any
  dragger.x = dragger.x;
  dragger.y = dragger.y;

  if(hitTestArray.length > 1){
    dragger.alpha = 1;
    stage.update(evt);
  }//else{

      if(intersect(tip, right)){  //Intersection testing for good (also tried 'dragger.drag' to see if that would work. it didn't)

          alert("YAY you're right AND it works!");
          dragger.alpha = 1;

      }else if(intersect(tip, wrong)){  //intersection Testing for bad

          alert("BOO its wrong, but YAY it works"); 
          dragger.alpha = 1;
      }

    stage.update(evt);
  //}
  }, this);
  ```

**UPDATED INTERSECT:**

- for testing intersection.

  ```
  function intersect(obj1, obj2){
    var objBounds1 = obj1.nominalBounds.clone();
    var objBounds2 = obj2.nominalBounds.clone();

    var pt = obj1.globalToLocal(objBounds2.x, objBounds2.y);



    var h1 = -(objBounds1.height / 2 + objBounds2.height);
    var h2 = objBounds2.height / 2;
    var w1 = -(objBounds1.width / 2 + objBounds2.width);
    var w2 = objBounds2.width / 2;


    if(pt.x > w2 || pt.x < w1) return false;
    if(pt.y > h2 || pt.y < h1) return false;

    return true;
  }
  ```

To sum up, I need to know how to make it not undefined so that I can test for that little box being in one of the big boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because you used `this.currentTarget` instead of `evt.currentTarget` on that one line.

Note that your actual code is not the same as the code you posted above. Here is the code in the live demo:

```
if(intersect(this.currentTarget.drag, right)){
    evt.currentTarget.alpha=0.2;
} else if(intersect(this.currentTarget.drag, wrong)){
    evt.currentTarget.alpha=0.7;
}
else{
    evt.currentTarget.alpha=1;
}
```

Not sure if this will solve all your issues, but it should at least get you moving forward.

---

**[UPDATE]**

Looking a little deeper, there a number of issues that are likely contributing to your intersect function not working:

1. Your right/left bounds are not correct. EaselJS objects do not have a `width` or `height` ([more info](http://blog.createjs.com/update-width-height-in-easeljs/)), so the bounds you set just have an `x` and `y`.

You can use `nominalBounds` to get the proper bounds. This provides the untransformed, original bounds of the symbol. You will have to account for any scaling. In this case, the bounds are:
* left: `{x: 0, y: 0, width: 275, height: 300}`
* right: `{x: 0, y: 0, width: 413, height: 430}`

2. Your intersection will have to consider the display list hierarchy. Specifically, when comparing position and size, they should be relative to each other. If your drag target is positioned inside another clip, it will need to consider the parent positioning. I recommend always doing `localToGlobal` on coordinates when comparing them.

Example:

```
// Find the clip's top/left position in the global scope
var p = myContainer.localToGlobal(myClip.x, myClip.y); 
// OR 
// Find the clip's position in the global scope
var p = myClip.localToGlobal(0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah the error's gone. Now I just need to better figure out why it's always returning false...

Comment: Posted some updates after looking through the source.

Comment: ohh.... dang so I guess that messes with any responsiveness I might want with this huh? I had another intersect function that I found on what seems to be a popular codepen that did a lot of this. I'll just use that one and make sure to change it to nominal bounds. I'll let you know how it goes! :)

Comment: As long as you account for scaling, it should be fine to make it responsive.

Comment: oh! that's good. I'm still very new and trying things by trial and error. when I looked into nominalBounds before, it seemed like it wouldn't work with that, so I tried to avoid it. That's good to know! :)

Comment: Ok, So i changed the code back to what I had found on a popular codepen. that part is working at least part of the time, but it seems like the offset is way off. anything to the left or above the targets counts as good, but then it stops halfway through the target area. see here for an updated version: http://apersonnamedmike.github.io/Drag-Drop-almost/